# Error: read ECONNRESET when using Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am getting the below error whenever I start the Android Emulator with `tns`. The emulator runs for a while and then it shows up. When the error shows up the debugger disconnects from the Android Emulator, stopping livesync.

[image: Android Emulator error]

The command I'm using to run the emulator is:

```
tns livesync android --emulator --watch
```

I've already tried reinstalling `tns` using `npm install -g nativescript`.

I've also reinstalled all the packages located in `package.json`. I'm currently going through the nativescript-angular tutorial online and using their code locally to follow along with.

Here's a link to the exact code and files I have locally:

https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/tree/angular-start

Anyone know what would be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes due to an unresponsive emulator or when you are trying to livesync a code that causes the emulator to halt (sometimes due to wrong XML or CSS file).
The solution is to simply rebuild your project (after removing the wrongful lines in the code if any).If that does not works try to remove the app from your emulator (make sure it is responsive - otherwise restart it) and then reset your projects node_modules and platforms

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf platforms

tns run android
```

Comment: This didn't work. After I deleted those folders, and then ran `tns run android`, the same error comes up as above but during the build process after the Android Emulator has already started and the home screen is showing. Once the build process finishes, the app is never deployed to the running emulator because that error has already happened.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this same issue :

In app.component.ts or any typescript file,

Instead of using template, Use **templateUrl** to point out the separate xml file to fix this issue.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

For More Reference: Check [this link](http://helpjavaandroidbeginers.blogspot.in/2017/05/error-read-econnreset-when-using.html)

**Note:** Again I faced this issue sometimes with my emulator.I solved this issue by deleted my old emulator and created new emulator then increased hard disk storage size to 1 GB.